# How to manage connection pool with Knex/generic-pool and Oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js

We use Knex with generic pool as our Query Builder and Pool Manager for our Oracle 11.2 Database.

The problem we are facing is that some time Knex / generic-pool starts to accumulate connections and cant recycle them.

I tried to pass some parameters to Knex / Generic Pool to make them kill connections after some point, but looks like it did not worked out.

Packges version:

- Knex: v0.13.0
- Oracledb: v1.13.1
- Generic Pool: v2.5.4

Knex configuration:

```
{
    client: 'oracledb',
    connection: {
        user: DB_USER,
        password: DB_PASSWORD,
        host: `${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}`,
        database: DB_NAME
    },
    debug: true,
    fetchAsString: ['number', 'clob'],
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 843600000,
    pool: {
        min: 2,
        max: 150,
        acquireTimeoutMillis: 100000,
        evictionRunIntervalMillis: 120000,
        maxWaitingClients: 100,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 100000
    }
}
```

[Openshift print with environment variable DEBUG="Knex:*" showing a lot of clients waiting for connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DepZs.png)

Comment: The generic pool may have a few nice features but you'll lose out on things like the lightweight node-oracledb connection pool ping with 12.2 client (which you can use to connect to 11.2 DB), and also all the things like FAN and AC.

Answer (score 0):

Try knex 0.14.2 some pool related problems were fixed in that. Also try to add some debug information when transactions are created/committed/rolled back. Open transactions will take connection from pool and does bot release it until transaction is ended. You can get information about pool and transacions bu running app with DEBUG=knex:* environment variable set.

Comment: Thks, I'm testing with Knex 0.14.2 in our homologation environment starting today. Will make a reply when I have more data to share.

Comment: Tried with Knex 0.14.2 but that didn't help. Apparentely the pool manager is unable to recycle the connections after some time.

Comment: Adding an update: we're using oracledb 3.0 now, with health check to clear the connections in case the application becames unresponsive. It's working better now.